# Nodejs Addons uv_queue_work segmentation fault

Tags: c++, node.js, libuv

I'm trying to create a very little nodejs addons example.
My c++ code is this:

```
void __sleep(uv_work_t* req) {
    usleep(1000 * 1000 * 5); // = 5seconds
}

void after(uv_work_t *handle, int status) {
    printf("After\n");
}

Handle<Value> foo(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    uv_loop_t *loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_work_t req;
    uv_queue_work(loop, &req, __sleep, after);
    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}

void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "foo", foo);
}

NODE_MODULE("myModule", InitAll)
```

In js, this:

```
console.log(myModule);
myModule.foo();
console.log("started sleeping...");
```

When i call `myModule.foo` function the process terminates with a segmentation fault.

I have tried to add `uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT)` but this blocks the main thread.

Where did I go wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `req` is allocated on stack and is freed when `foo` returns. You need to allocate it on heap (using `new` or `malloc`) and free it manually when you are done (for example, in `after` callback)