# libuv uv_queue_work crash

Tags: c++, c, node.js, libuv

I am just learning Node.js native module, and I get an error when I run the following simple code.

*main.cpp* (I create Win32 console application called UVTEST.exe in Visual Studio 2013)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <uv.h>

static void downloadFile(uv_work_t* req)
{
    printf("downloading ...");
}

static void afterDownload(uv_work_t* req, int status)
{
    printf("success ...");
}

int main()
{
    uv_loop* loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_work_t* req = new uv_work_t();

    // the following uv_queue_work function CRASH
    uv_queue_work(loop, req, downloadFile, afterDownload);

    uv_run(loop,UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    return 0;
}
```

*uv.h: C:\Users\xxx.node-gyp\0.12.7\deps\uv\include 

linker: C:\Users\xxx.node-gyp\0.12.7\x64\node.lib*

I get an exception in VS2013: 
**Unhandled exception at 0x00002B992DDFA232 in UVTEST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00002B992DDFA232.**

I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: I have read [Nodejs Addons uv_queue_work segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880486/nodejs-addons-uv-queue-work-segmentation-fault) but my question is not that reason.

Comment: after using libuv complied by myself instead of node.lib, i get everything ok. so there is no need to answer this question any more.